# Improving the rendering performance

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am building a website that shows a brain of a fish with thousands of neurons.
The brain model is being loaded from the database as triangles (faces), and each triangle (face) consists of 3 points.

The neurons are being loaded from the database as links (lines), and each link consists of 2 points (line).

The rendering takes a very long time and I couldn't find a way to improve the performance. There must be a problem in my way of building the meshes and geometries of the scene (since I am new to WebGL).

The following image is an example of the models with a sub-set of the neurons:

[image]

### The rendering code:

I haven't inluded the complete code because the page contains many functionalities like searching.
Also I haven't included the mouse controls and raycasts.

```
<script>

    var container;
    var camera, controls, scene, renderer;       
    var brain;
    var dirLight;
    var viewport_width;
    var viewport_height;
    var neurons;
    var line_width = 2;    
    var show_brain = true;
    var selected_brain_resolution = {{ brain.resolution }};

    init();
    animate();


    function init() {    

        {% for n in aligned_neurons %}

            random_color = getRandomColor();          
            colors_scheme.push(random_color);            

        {% endfor %}        

        container = document.getElementById('visualization');

        viewport_width = container.clientWidth;
        viewport_height = 0.75 * viewport_width;

        renderer_offset_rectangle = container.getBoundingClientRect();

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, viewport_width / viewport_height, 1, 100000);
        camera.position.z = 1000;

        renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
        renderer.setClearColor(0xcccccc);
        renderer.setPixelRatio(viewport_width / viewport_height);
        renderer.setSize(viewport_width, viewport_height);
        renderer.sortObjects = false;
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


        neurons = new THREE.Group();
        brain = new THREE.Group();
        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        draw_neurons();

        if (show_brain) {
            draw_brain();
        }
        brain.rotation.z = 3.14;
        brain.add(neurons);
        scene.add(brain);

        draw_intersection_plane();

        dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
        dirLight.position.set(camera.position.x, camera.position.y, camera.position.z);
        scene.add(dirLight);

    }

 function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        render();
    }

    function render() {

        dirLight.position.set(camera.position.x, camera.position.y, camera.position.z);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    function draw_brain() {

        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        var counter = 0;

        {% for face in brain.face_set.all %}

            v1 = new THREE.Vector3(({{ face.pt_1.x }}-{{ brain.center.x }}), ({{ face.pt_1.y }}-{{ brain.center.y }}), {{ face.pt_1.z }}-{{ brain.center.z }});
            v2 = new THREE.Vector3(({{ face.pt_2.x }}-{{ brain.center.x }}), ({{ face.pt_2.y }}-{{ brain.center.y }}), {{ face.pt_2.z }}-{{  brain.center.z }});
            v3 = new THREE.Vector3(({{ face.pt_3.x }}-{{ brain.center.x }}), ({{ face.pt_3.y }}-{{ brain.center.y }}), {{ face.pt_3.z }}-{{  brain.center.z }});

            geometry.vertices.push(v1);
            geometry.vertices.push(v2);
            geometry.vertices.push(v3);

            index0 = counter;
            index1 = counter + 1;
            index2 = counter + 2;

            geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(index0, index1, index2));                
            counter += 3;

        {% endfor %}

        geometry.computeFaceNormals();

        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            wireframe: false,
            color: 0xcccccc,
            specular: 0xffffff,
            shininess: 30,
            opacity: 0.5
        });

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);        
        brain.add(mesh)
    }

    function draw_neurons() {

        {% for neuron in aligned_neurons %}           

            var color = colors_scheme[{{ forloop.counter0 }}];
            var soma_material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                wireframe: false,
                color: color,
                specular: 0xffffff,
                shininess: 30
            });

            var line_material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: color, linewidth: line_width});

            var spheregeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 10, 10);
            var soma = new THREE.Mesh(spheregeometry, soma_material);
            soma.position.set({{ neuron.view.0.start_node.position.x }}-{{  brain.center.x }},
                    {{ neuron.view.0.start_node.position.y }}-{{  brain.center.y }},
                    {{ neuron.view.0.start_node.position.z }}-{{  brain.center.z }});
            var radius = 7;           

                {% for link in neuron.view %}

                    var n_position = new THREE.Vector3({{ link.start_node.position.x }} -{{  brain.center.x }}, {{ link.start_node.position.y }}-{{ brain.center.y }}, {{ link.start_node.position.z }}-{{ brain.center.z }});
                    var p_position = new THREE.Vector3({{ link.end_node.position.x }} -{{  brain.center.x }}, {{ link.end_node.position.y }}-{{ brain.center.y }}, {{ link.end_node.position.z }} -{{ brain.center.z }});

                    var line_geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
                    line_geometry.vertices.push(n_position, p_position);
                    var line = new THREE.Line(line_geometry, line_material);

                    neurons.add(line);

                {% endfor %}           

            soma.scale.set(radius, radius, radius);
            neurons.add(soma);


        {% endfor %}
    }
</script>
```

Would you please give me any advice or suggestion to improve the performance?
Thank you very much

Comment: The first problem I see is that you are using the `THREE.CanvasRenderer`.  Use `THREE.WebGLRenderer` instead.

Comment: @2pha I did, but it is still performing very slow.
Also, the lights are different now and the brain model looks like it was built from Metal.

Comment: Btw, one minor detail if I understand correctly: you only need to call geometry.computeFaceNormals() once, outside of the for-loop. But I don't think that's the cause of the slow rendering.

Comment: Regarding the brain model looking like it was built from Metal, you probably want to use MeshLambertMaterial rather than MeshPhongMaterial.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to look into using [BufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry). There are various examples of rendering many vertices/faces in a fast/efficient manner.

- How many vertices are you creating in draw_brain()?
- How many neuron spheres are you creating in draw_neurons()?
- How many neuron lines are you creating in draw_neurons()?

On that note, if you remove the brain mesh, does it improve performance? If you remove the neurons mesh(es), does it improve performance?

Off the bat, I can see that you can probably optimize the way you're constructing the THREE.Line in draw_neurons(). If I understand correctly, the lines in each neuron share the same material, so you only need a single geometry and a single THREE.LineSegments mesh (rather than a separate geometry/THREE.Line for each line/segment) in this specific case.

Comment: Thanks I have learnt a lot from your answer, but actuallyI have figured out the main reason of the slowness which is the {% for %} loop from Django which repeats the code thousands of times! so the slowlyness is still there even with your solution which I am following right now :D
I am trying to find a way to iterate over my points with java script "for" loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small note to the msun's answer. BufferGeometry() has a very useful method

```
.fromGeometry ( Geometry )
```

Populates this BufferGeometry with data from a Geometry object. So with small changes of your code you can do

```
var bufgeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry( geometry );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(bufgeometry, material);        
brain.add(mesh);
```